# How did I overwrite my whole python program with this command prompt command?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

So I was putting in some values into a Python program I have written (what it does is irrelevant):

> E:\Users\Me\Desktop\Python>idtohex.py
>
> Enter ID: 213467
>
> DB 41 03

Nice, it works alright. Now at this point I had accidentally copied this string to my clipboard:

> [Newline here]
>
> E:\Users\Me\Desktop\Python>idtohex.py

From when I had originally started the program in the command prompt.

Now, because of the newline my program crashes as it couldn't handle the input (oops):

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Because of this error I am now returned to the command prompt and the next line from my clipboard is entered, which is trying to run this command:

> E:\Users\Me\Desktop\Python>idtohex.py

The command prompt gives me this error so I think it's not a big deal and just get on with it:

> 'E:\Users\Me\Desktop\Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.

Now I try to run the program again and my whole program is completely empty.  [Overwritten. 0-bytes on disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej0bs.png). So with that simple mistake I somehow overwrote my whole program and have no way to get it back.

How the ***hell*** does this happen within the Windows command prompt?

Comment: This line: `E:\Users\Me\Desktop\Python>idtohex.py` means "execute the program at the given path and store its output into idtohex.py file", as usual. If the command does not exist, its output is empty, so the result stored in the .py file is 0 bytes...

Comment: You should investigate using an IDE instead of the legacy command prompt.

Comment: Did you really enter all of `E:\Users\Me\Desktop\Python>idtohex.py` at the command prompt? Were you not aware that `E:\Users\Me\Desktop\Python>` represents the _prompt itself_ - which you should have seen when you opened the terminal - and you're only supposed to enter `idtohex.py`?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, cmd.exe is certainly a legacy shell (it goes back to OS/2 and it's based on MS-DOS COMMAND.COM), but you can't say the same about powershell.exe (also a console application, i.e. a client of conhost.exe). For 3.6b1 (12 Sep),  CPython is revamping the raw I/O layer for the Windows console to support Unicode using the wide-character API (the raw layer transcodes between UTF-16 and UTF-8, since working with bytes as UTF-8 is a better fit in Python). So console scripts and the python.exe REPL will no longer be limited to legacy codepages. Yay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before running a command, cmd.exe sets up its standard handles for the child process to inherit. The `>` operator redirects a file descriptor to a file opened for output, and it truncates an existing file to 0 bytes. It defaults to file descriptor 1 (standard output, or stdout). Since the only output is the error message on file descriptor 2 (standard error, stderr), the resulting file is empty. If you had run `E:\Users\Me\Desktop\Python 2>idtohex.py` (the space is necessary in this case for parsing), the file would instead get overwritten by the error message.